# How to extract values from this string in php

Tags: php

I have this string

```
@[181] @[183] @[4563]
```

from this string I want to get values between [] in this case

181,183,4563

Comment: Look into regex and `preg_match_all()`, which makes it quite simple.

Comment: check out Preg_match() i believe this will help more than explode() or str_replace()....there are tons of examples of how to extract numbers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$string = '@[181] @[183] @[4563]';
preg_match_all('/\[([0-9]*)\]/', $string, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$string = '@[181] @[183] @[4563]';
preg_match_all("#\[([^\]]+)\]#", $string, $matches); //or #\[(.*?)\]#
print_r($matches[1]);
?> 

Array
(
    [0] => 181
    [1] => 183
    [2] => 4563
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it might sound sexy to use regex and all, but this is a case where you might not need the full power/overhead, as you have a very well formatted input string.

```
$string = '@[181] @[183] @[4563]';
$needles = array('@', '[', ']');
$cleaned_string = str_replace($needles, '', $string);
$result_array = explode(' ', $cleaned_string);
```

Comment: Or you could replace space with comma instead of exploding, given he wants to output it as `181,183,4563`

Answer (score 0):

assuming the values between the array are numbers this is pretty simple

```
 $s =  '@[181] @[183] @[4563]';
 preg_match_all('/\d+/', $s, $m);

 $matches_as_array = $m[0];
 $matches_as_string = implode(',', $m[0]);
```